# Komodo Edit 10 Autocomplete not show options' list

Tags: text, editor, komodo

Komodo Edit 10 Autocomplete not show options' list as notepad++, when I press "ctrl+space". It just fills with the first option, instead of list them to me choose the right one.

It does such horrible thing. Is there a way to fix it, and make him show the options when I press "ctrl+space" as on notepad++, instead of just fill with the first one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not supported by Komodo Edit 10.

However, here there is this feature request ticket:
https://github.com/Komodo/KomodoEdit/issues/1896